# Как у нас Ангел попал в тетраморф, к зверушкам, и что делать с тире и иными знаками?

Tags: пунктуация

**Апокалиптические животные, или Тетраморф**

Иоанн:

> И первое животное было подобно льву, и второе животное подобно тельцу,
>   и третье животное имело лице, как человек, и четвёртое животное
>   подобно орлу летящему. И каждое из четырёх животных имело по шести
>   крыл вокруг, а внутри они исполнены очей...

У меня:

> ...Каждый из этих образов вскоре стал символом одного из евангелистов.
>   Так, Ангел обозначает человеческую природу Христа и его воплощение –
>   евангелие от Матфея. Лев – указывает на господство и власть Христа, на
>   его Воскресение – и это евангелие от Марка. Бык – это
>   священнодейственное достоинство Христа и его крестная жертва —
>   евангелие от Луки и Орёл — дар Святого Духа и Вознесение Господне
>   символизирует евангелие от Иоанна.

И как же ж жить?..

Comment: А почему бы не использовать скобки для ссылок на евангелие?

Comment: Символом одного из евангелистов или самого евнагелия (Орёл — символизирует евангелие от Иоанна)?

Comment: Это вариант. Пусть автор думает, я предложу. Оформляй красивенько ответом! )))

Comment: И про кто на ком стоял подумаем... ДАВАЙ ОТВЕТ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложный текст с точки зрения грамматики, в которую он плохо вписывается, поэтому обойтись без редактирования не получается.

Каждый из этих образов вскоре стал символом **для** одного из евангелистов. Так, Ангел обозначает человеческую природу Христа и его воплощение **в евангелии от Матфея.** Лев указывает на господство и власть Христа, на его Воскресение – **и это евангелие от Марка**. Бык, священнодейственное достоинство Христа и его крестная жертва,  — **в евангелии от Луки** и Орёл — дар Святого Духа и Вознесение Господне символизирует **евангелие от Иоанна.**

Comment: У нас получилось *Орёл — символизирует евангелие от Иоанна*. (((

Comment: "воплощение в евангелии"?

Comment: Я считаю, что это присоединительная конструкция. Бык в евангелии от Луки  и Орел - это как бы назывные предложения, связанные союзом И, поэтому нет запятой. А после Орла присоединительное предложение.

Comment: Я думаю... Отсылаю последние вопросы с сайта автору.

Answer (score 1):

Сколько образов: четыре или пять (добавился Ангел)?

Каждый из этих образов вскоре стал символом одного из евангелистов, или символом евангелия, или использован в евангелии?

Ссылки на евангелие можно оформить в скобках:

**...Каждый из этих образов вскоре стал символом одного из евангелистов. Так, Ангел обозначает человеческую природу Христа и его воплощение (евангелие от Матфея), Лев указывает на господство и власть Христа, на его Воскресение (евангелие от Марка), Бык – это священнодейственное достоинство Христа и его крестная жертва (евангелие от Луки), а Орёл — дар Святого Духа и Вознесение Господне (евангелие от Иоанна).**

Comment: Я теперь думаю: у Иоанна - *третье животное имело лице, как человек*, - возможно, авторская ошибка - назвать "животное с лицем" Ангелом...

Comment: Похоже, вы правы. Всего 4 образа. Только животное с человеческим лицом — у Матфея, а не у Иоанна.

Comment: Спасибо. У Иоанна - в цитате, верхней. А про Матфея - это обратно же к автору...

Comment: По поводу скобок. Текст изложен понятно, но в скобки заключают дополнительную информацию, а у нас  она вроде бы основная: "Каждый из этих образов вскоре стал символом одного из евангелистов". Тогда это предложение надо корректировать, например:  Каждый евангелист использует один из образов.